# LUA context format beginner

Tags: lua

I've updated this to show the entire code I'm working with. In hindsight I shouldn't have attempted to make it shorthand. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
--[[Checks to see if a player owns 1 of 12 buildings.]]--
events.FactionTurnStart[#events.FactionTurnStart+1] = function(context)
    if (conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Smithing_1_Blacksmith_Iwate", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Smithing_2_Weaponsmith_Iwate", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Smithing_3_Master_Weaponsmith_Iwate", context)) then
        Player_Iwate = ""
    else
        Player_Iwate = "Inf_Four_Iwate_Nodachi"
    end
end

events.FactionTurnStart[#events.FactionTurnStart+1] = function(context)
    if (conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Ninja_1_Hideout_Iga", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Ninja_2_Ninjutsu_School_Iga", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Ninja_3_Clan_Fortress_Iga", context)) then
        Player_Iga = ""
    else
        Player_Iga = "Inf_Four_Iga_Kisho_Ninja"
    end
end

events.FactionTurnStart[#events.FactionTurnStart+1] = function(context)
    if (conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Horses_1_Pastures_Mikawa", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Horses_2_Breeders_Mikawa", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Horses_3_Warhorse_Breeders_Mikawa", context)) then
        Player_Mikawa = ""
    else
        Player_Mikawa = "Inf_Four_Mikawa_Mounted_Ninja"
    end
end

events.FactionTurnStart[#events.FactionTurnStart+1] = function(context)
    if (conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Horses_1_Pastures_Kai", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Horses_2_Breeders_Kai", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Horses_3_Warhorse_Breeders_Kai", context)) then
        Player_Kai = ""
    else
        Player_Kai = "Inf_Four_Kai_Light_Cavalry"
    end
end

events.FactionTurnStart[#events.FactionTurnStart+1] = function(context)
    if (conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Smithing_1_Blacksmith_Satsuma", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Smithing_2_Armourer_Satsuma", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Smithing_3_Master_Armourer_Satsuma", context)) then
        Player_Satsuma = ""
    else
        Player_Satsuma = "Inf_Four_Satsuma_Katana_Samurai"
    end
end

events.FactionTurnStart[#events.FactionTurnStart+1] = function(context)
    if (conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Naval_1_Merchant_Colony_Bungo", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Naval_2_Warehouses_Bungo", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Naval_3_Red_Seal_Company_Bungo", context)) then
        Player_Bungo = ""
    else
        Player_Bungo = "Inf_Four_Bungo_Matchlock"
    end
end

events.FactionTurnStart[#events.FactionTurnStart+1] = function(context)
    if (conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Holy_Site_1_Holy_Site_Aki", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Holy_Site_2_Pilgrim_Hostel_Aki", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Holy_Site_3_Great_Soja_Shrine_Aki", context)) then
        Player_Aki = ""
    else
        Player_Aki = "Inf_Four_Aki_Wako_Raiders"
    end
end

events.FactionTurnStart[#events.FactionTurnStart+1] = function(context)
    if (conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Timber_1_Lumbercamp_Tosa", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Timber_2_Lumberyards_Tosa", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Timber_3_Sawmills_Tosa", context)) then
        Player_Tosa = ""
    else
        Player_Tosa = "Inf_Four_Tosa_Yumi_Samurai"
    end
end

events.FactionTurnStart[#events.FactionTurnStart+1] = function(context)
    if (conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Craftwork_1_Artisans_Echizen", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Craftwork_2_Fletchers_Echizen", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Craftwork_3_Master_Bowmaker_Echizen", context)) then
        Player_Echizen = ""
    else
        Player_Echizen = "Inf_Four_Echizen_Katana_Ronin"
    end
end

events.FactionTurnStart[#events.FactionTurnStart+1] = function(context)
    if (conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Farming_1_Rice_Paddies_Owari", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Farming_2_Irrigation_Owari", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Farming_3_Terraces_Owari", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Farming_4_Consolidation_Owari", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Farming_5_Specialization_Owari", context)) then
        Player_Owari = ""
    else
        Player_Owari = "Inf_Four_Owari_Long"
    end
end

events.FactionTurnStart[#events.FactionTurnStart+1] = function(context)
    if (conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Gold_Mining_1_Surface_Mining_Izu", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Gold_Mining_2_Open_Pit_Izu", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Gold_Mining_3_Mining_Complex_Izu", context)) then
        Player_Izu = ""
    else
        Player_Izu = "Inf_Four_Izu_Mortar_Team"
    end
end

events.FactionTurnStart[#events.FactionTurnStart+1] = function(context)
    if (conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Naval_1_Merchant_Colony_Echigo", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Naval_2_Warehouses_Echigo", context) or conditions.FactionBuildingExists(Player_Faction, "SHO_Region_Specialty_Naval_3_Red_Seal_Company_Echigo", context)) then
        Player_Echigo = ""
    else
        Player_Echigo = "Inf_Four_Echigo_Marathon_Monks"
    end
end
```

--The above code works as intended because if I use one at a time in the CampaignSettlementAttack event it will work. The Player could have any combination of all 12 so I'm trying to avoid making thousands of factionturnstart events.

--the code below doesn't work because of the way it writes the player values with the "" between each unit. At the very bottom I put an example of how the units are supposed to be laid out in order for the code to work. I can't figure out how to get the player value to match the format required.

```
events.CampaignSettlementAttacked[#events.CampaignSettlementAttacked+1] = function(context)
    if conditions.IsPlayerTurn(context) and not conditions.IsBesieging(context) and conditions.SettlementName("settlement:jap_yamashiro:kyoto", context) and not kill_switch_kyoto then
        kill_switch_kyoto = true
        scripting.game_interface:create_force("ashikaga", Player_Iwate,Player_Iga,Player_Mikawa,Player_Kai,Player_Satsuma,Player_Bungo,Player_Aki,Player_Tosa,Player_Echizen,Player_Owari,Player_Izu,Player_Echigo, -42.0, -123.0, "Kyoto Nightmare", true)
        return false
    end
    return false
end
```

The effect will work if written like below

```
scripting.game_interface:create_force("ashikaga", "Inf_Four_Iwate_Nodachi,Inf_Four_Iga_Kisho_Ninja,Inf_Four_Mikawa_Mounted_Ninja,Inf_Four_Satsuma_Katana_Samurai", -42.0, -123.0, "Kyoto Nightmare", true)
```

I was able to resolve the problem and get it working by changing the effect like below. Thank you for your responses.

```
scripting.game_interface:create_force("ashikaga", ('"' .. ',' .. Player_Izu .. ',' .. Player_Echigo .. ',' .. Player_Iga .. ',' .. Player_Echizen .. ',' .. Player_Owari .. ',' .. Player_Tosa .. ',' .. Player_Aki .. ',' .. Player_Bungo .. ',' .. Player_Iwate .. ',' .. Player_Satsuma .. ',' .. Player_Kai .. ',' .. Player_Mikawa .. ',' .. '"'), -42.0, -123.0, "Kyoto Nightmare", true)
```

Comment: what is this about? There are no players in Lua, which API are you talking about? it is not quite clear what you want to achieve and I don't see how you can save "thousands of lines of code" here. please don't exaggerate.

Comment: You still haven't told us your framework/library. `events` is not part of vanilla Lua.

Comment: I'm an amateur hobbyist I don't know exactly what your asking. I have gathered a list of events, conditions and effects and have been fairly successful in writing what I want to happen in game. I assumed this issue I'm having would have an lua universal solution.

Comment: Lua is a very simple language designed mainly for embedding in other programs. [Here is its website.](https://www.lua.org/) Your code looks like it may be written for a program that embeds Lua, like a specific game or a game engine like [Love2d](https://love2d.org/). It would be helpful to add a tag to your question for that embedding program, if one exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
Player_1 = "Unit_1" else Player_1 = ""

Player_2 = "Unit_2" else Player_2 = ""
```

This is syntactic nonsense. else is part of a conditional statement. You cannot use it like this.

Either do this:

```
if condition then
  Player_1 = "Unit_1"
else
  Player_1 = ""
end
```

or

```
Player_1 = condition and "Unit_1" or ""
```

It is not clear what you actually want to achieve. If I had to guess I would propose:

local players = {"Unit_1", "Unit_2"}
scripting.game_interface:create_force(table.concat(players, ","), true)

Assuming that 12 players have Unit_1 .. Unit_12 you can simply do

```
local unit = ""
for 1,12 do
  unit = unit .. "Unit_" .. i .. ","
end
scripting.game_interface:create_force(unit, true)
```

Comment: I've updated my post to show the entire code I'm working with. I thank you for the assistance.